# Algolia browse function returning max 1000 records using Javascript

Tags: javascript, algolia

I am using algolia javascript api for retrieving all records in my index using browse function, but still it is returning 1000 records. Here is my code:

```
function load_location_list(){
var client = algoliasearch('ID', 'KEY');
var index_name = "locations_new";
var attribute_list = "*";
var index = client.initIndex(index_name);
index.browse({
    "attributesToRetrieve": attribute_list,
}).then(function search_Success(response) {
        console.log(response);
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `browse` doesn't return more than 1000 elements at the first call. However, the response contains a `cursor` that you can use to access the next elements with the `browseFrom` function.

However, the previous method is kind of manual. You probably want to use the `browseAll` function instead which lets you access all the elements sequentially.

You can find more informations about all the `browse*` functions in the [README of the JS client](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-js#backup--export-an-index) (also available in the [Algolia documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/javascript#backup--export-an-index)).